# Integration of $A$-valued functions (Functional Analysis)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Premise 1: my source is the Rudin - Functional Analysis.

Premise 2: i'm not a mathmo so forgive for the mistakes

A couple of question on the subject... 
An example of Banach Algebra is the set of the bounded linear operators $\cal{B}(X)$ where $X$ is a banach space.

On the definition of integral (section 10.22) it says

*If $A$ is a Banach algebra and $f$ is a continous $A$-valued function on some compact Hausdorf space $Q$ on which a complex Borel measure $\mu$ is defined then $\int f d\mu$ exists...*

I'm just trying to find some example of such integral (i.e. i want to see an integral written that meets such definition). To such purpose i'm trying to construct it by myself however i got stuck...

So can you provide me an example?

Update,

i had a look to the definitions you provided me, i also had a look to the definition the book i'm studying from states. It says that the integral $y = \int_X x d\mu$ is well defined if for each $\Lambda \in X^*$ we have

$$\Lambda y = \int_X \Lambda x d\mu$$

Following this example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470405/understanding-a-theorem-10-25-from-rudin-comparison-with-method-to-solve-differe/1470573#1470573) and the definition i just gave
would be possible to compute something like $$\int_{C^1[0,1]} \left( d/dx \right) d \mu$$ ?

In this case i would suspect the "value" is something like $I$, however how to prove that for each functional $\Lambda$ we have

$$\Lambda I = \int_{C^1[0,1]} \Lambda \left( d/dx \right) d \mu$$

I'm not neither sure of what i'm talking about, but i really would like to understand this concept of "weird integral".

Thank you

Comment: $A=\Bbb {C} $ is a Banach Algebra, $Q=[0,1] $ is compact Hausdorff and the Lebesgue measure is a complex Borel measure on this space. Although this may not be the most interesting example, the above shows that any continuous function on the unit interval will do.

Comment: I actually was hoping something involving linear bounded operator... since actually with "simple" spaces i know what i could expect... con you provide an example more involved?

Comment: @Lukki you should look at Bochner integral, Pettis integral. For general theory of such integration see Vector Measures by Diestel and Uhl. The main applcation of this type of integration is a spectral theorem for normal operators on Hilbert spaces.