# Understanding a theorem 10.25 from Rudin comparison with method to solve differential equations.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm going to be very informal... so i hope i'm going to make my point anyway... otherwise tell me what i should adjust in this question.

The theorem 10.25 of rudin - functional analysis states that in a banach algebra we can define a "rational" function as the following

$$R(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma} R(\lambda)(\lambda e - x)^{-1} d\lambda$$

The integral i reported is specifically defined for banach algebra value (there's another question where i've asked an example of that), and $R(\lambda)$ is defined as

$$R(\lambda) = P(\lambda) + \sum_{m,k} c_{m,k}(\lambda - \alpha_{m})^{-k}$$

where $\alpha_m$ are poles of the rational function $R(\lambda)$. I was wandering if there's some kind of relationship between such integral and the methods to solve differential equation (that usually people learn in basic analysis courses). For example... if $$A = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + 2\frac{d}{dx} + 5$$

To solve such equation we use the polynomial

$$p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 + 2 \lambda + 5$$.

Is there some relationships?

Comment: Did you look up the Laplace transform? That would answer the last part of your question.

Comment: Yep, of course i know the laplace transform (it allows to transform a differential equation in an algebraic one).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two topics can have something to do with each other, except that the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ is not bounded. Consider the differential $\partial = \frac{d}{dx}$ on $C[0,1]$ with domain $\mathcal{D}(\partial)$ consisting of all continuously differentiable functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ for which $f(0)=0$. Then
$$
        \partial : \mathcal{D}(\partial)\subset C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]
$$
has a resolvent $(\partial-\lambda I)^{-1}$, where $g=(\partial -\lambda I)^{-1}f$ is the unique solution of
$$
                             g'-\lambda g = f \\
                                g(0) = 0.
$$
The solution is found using an integrating factor of $e^{-\lambda t}$:
$$
         (\partial -\lambda I)^{-1}f = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)e^{\lambda(x-t)}dt.
$$
This is a strange example because $\partial$ on this domain *has no spectrum*!

Suppose you want to now solve
$$
           \left(\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+2\frac{d}{dx}+5\right)f=g,\\
                      f(0)=0,\;\; f'(0)=0.
$$
This is the same as $p(\partial)f=g$.
Write $p(\lambda)=(\lambda^{2}+2\lambda+5)=(\lambda+1+2i)(\lambda+1-2i)$, integrate around the roots of $p$, and see what you get
$$
\begin{align}
       &\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}\frac{1}{p(\lambda)}(\lambda I-\partial)^{-1}gd\lambda \\
& =-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}\frac{1}{p(\lambda)}(\partial-\lambda I)^{-1}gd\lambda\\
  & = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}\frac{1}{p(\lambda)}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-\lambda t}g(t)dt d\lambda \\
  & = -\int_{0}^{x}\left[\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{C}\frac{e^{\lambda(x-t)}}{p(\lambda)}d\lambda\right]g(t)dt
\end{align}
$$
This is an integral solution where the integral kernel is found by evaluating
$$
     \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}\frac{e^{\lambda(x-t)}}{(\lambda-(-1-2i))(\lambda-(-1+2i))}d\lambda \\
   = \frac{e^{(-1-2i)(x-t)}}{-1-2i-(-1+2i)}+\frac{e^{(-1+2i)(x-t)}}{-1+2i-(-1-2i)} \\
   = -\frac{1}{4i}(e^{(1+2i)(t-x)}-e^{(2-i)(t-x)}) \\
   = -\frac{e^{(t-x)}}{2}\sin(2(t-x)).
$$
The final solution obtained using this method is
$$
          f(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}g(t)e^{(t-x)}\sin(2(t-x))dt.
$$
You can probably see that this method is going to give you the same thing as playing around with the operators directly:
$$
              (\partial^{2}+2\partial+5I)f=g.
$$
A functional calculus such as this turns operator manipulations into algebraic manipulations on fractions/polynomials in $\lambda$ because manipulating the algebraic expressions in the integrand becomes equivalent to manipulating the operators outside the integral.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30080/discussion-on-answer-by-trialanderror-understanding-a-theorem-10-25-from-rudin-c). Sorry about using a blunt instrument and deleting everything from here. There is, of course, no obligation to any party to continue the discussion in the chatroom. If you need to retrieve a specific, just @-ping me or flag this post for moderator attention.

Comment: @TrialAndError i've reviewed the material of the Rudin, Chapter 3, where basically the integral of "vector valued functions" si defined, in the case of study in my question basically given a vector $x$ and a given measure $\mu$ the integral $\int_X x d\mu$ is defined as a vector $y$ such that for each functional $\Lambda$ we have $\Lambda y = \int_X \Lambda x d\mu$ is this definition the key of your explanation?

Comment: So basically my question now would be, how to define $\Lambda$ such that the integral is well defined? (i'm not sure such question is properly asked, however i think i made my point).